# How to integrate site admin page with WordPress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, integration

I am going to build a site that is mainly a word press blog, but the blog will have a link to a shop area where you can purchase products.

I am going to have to build an admin page for the site owner to add/remove products. Since they are already going to be using the WordPress admin for their blog, I am wanting to integrate the products-admin into the WordPress  admin so the owner can easily administer everything from one central location.

I am not a blogger and don't have much experience with blog software so before I started poking around I wanted to ask if their was a best practice or standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the WP-Ecommerce WordPress plugin. You can run your shop and everything directly from WordPress. Everything's integrated.

Comment: Here's a link to the plug-in: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/  Or you can download and install directly from the WordPress admin page.

Comment: Damn, nobody think that topic starter has developed EXCLUSIVE and CUSTOM solution for his customer and WP-Ecommerce have no such functionality.

Comment: ??? Clearly you thought so. And you left an answer accordingly. I didn't think so. And I left an answer accordingly. Given your poor English, though, I really can't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to put link to your `products admin area` from `wordpress admin area`. You can put such link using WordPress plugins.

Pluses are...

- you haven't to go deep into WordPress plugins to intergrate
- you haven't to do new design for your admin area (belive me - it will waste a lot of time)

Minuses are...

- admin should be logged in your `products admin area`; another way he would be asked to auth at your admin panel

**UPDATED:** More easies way is to show your `products admin area` in  integrated into Wordpress admin using plugin.